# What is ∃ in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I stumbled upon this symbol and I'm not sure at all what this symbol denotes.

[image]

Can someone decode this for me?

Comment: It means "there exists".  In the context given, it means "there exists some $v$ such that $uv=w$".

Comment: It means "there exists an element v such that".  In this case you have a set of all elements u were there exists a v such that u*v = w.

Comment: Thank you lulu. Can you post an answer so that I can credit you.

Comment: As a side note, the $\LaTeX$ for $\exists$ is `\exists`.  You  might be interested to read [this link](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~anne/WQ2007/mat67-Common_Math_Symbols.pdf) on several other common math symbols and short bits of their history.  If you can read German as well, [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN266833020_0039&DMDID=DMDLOG_0032&LOGID=LOG_0032&PHYSID=PHYS_0182) is a link to Gerhard Gentzen's 1935 paper where he tried to standardize notation and first used the $\forall$ symbol.  (starts on page 176).

Comment: This is very undesirable and humiliating when you see people down voting your question just because it way too easy for someone else to answer. I just want to say that person please search that same question in Google and let me know how easy is it for someone not from core mathematics background to find out this answer.

Comment: I guess this is why tools like Quora is getting popular. This is way too senseless.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the photo you posted in the question? Usually, there should be an index for notations in an introductory book for set theory.

Comment: I'm reading a paper where they have used these notations in bunch. For some notations they have explicitly expressed the meaning, but for common Set theory notations author didn't put any reference.

Comment: It will probably come up soon enough so I will tell you that "$\exists ! x$" means the $x$ that exists is the unique such $x$. Unique with respect to the property in context.

Comment: I'm surprised you managed to get that symbol into your title without learning what it means in the process. The [Google results for ∃](https://www.google.com/search?q=∃) are decently informative, as are the results for [backwards E](https://www.google.com/search?q=backwards+e).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it means "there exists". it could also mean "for some" or "we can find"

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\exists$ means "there exist". It is use to show that a particular element "exists" in the set or $\not \exists$ to specify "there does not exists".

For example: $\exists x: P(x)$ means there exists atleast one $x$ for which $P(x)$ is true.